# What does "no short description for property" from phpDoc mean?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm getting this critical error when running phpDoc on a class file of mine:

```
No short description for property $id.
```

This is the relevant code:

```php
/** @type int The user's id. */
private $id = 0;
```

I believe this is the way [used in the documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/introduction/definitions.html).

So what does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@var` instead of `@type`:

```
/**
 * @var integer The user's id. 
 */
private $id = 0;
```

Comment: Cool, it works, thanks! But then the documentation must be wrong, or I am misinterpreting... do you have some reference?

Comment: Seems that phpdoc2 not have a documentation already where phpdoc1's server gives me internal server errors. :( So you'll just have to believe me :) I've used `@var` since years

Comment: [PHPDocumetor tag reference](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html) However it gaves me Internal Server Errors